# Difference between these assumptions?

Tags: logic

If given some statement $P$ about natural numbers, what is the difference between the following: "Assume $k \in \mathbb {N}$ and $P(k)$" $(1)$, and the second way, "Assume $\exists k \in \mathbb {N}: P(k)$"$(2)$. I have seen contradictory answers online and I would like full clarification, thanks.

Comment: In (1) $k$ is a fixed number. The variable $k$ is free. In (2) there is no free variable. It is a statement. The letter $k$ may be replaced (twice) by any other letter.

Comment: Is saying something is free and fixed not contradictory?

Comment: Let $Q(k)$ be: $k\in \Bbb N$ and $P(k).$ In $Q(k),$ the variable $k$ is free. This is a syntactical notion. In the sentence "Assume $Q(k)$", you are talking about some fixed predefined $k.$

Comment: So that is the correct assumption we should use for induction? What is wrong with using $(2)$ for induction? Thanks Anne!

Comment: For proving an induction step $$(\forall k\in\Bbb N)(P(k)\implies P(k+1)),$$the correct assumption is (1).

Comment: Thanks, and why in particular is $2$ wrong, they seem very familiar to me but I need to read more on free variables and stuff, do you have reading material you think is particular good?

Comment: Sorry I don't. (2) is wrong because (1) is right. And (1) is right because any proof of $(\forall k\in X) R(k)$ begins with "Assume $k\in X,$ let us prove $R(k)$", and any proof of $A\implies B$ begins with "Assume $A,$ let us prove $B$".

Comment: I just can't justify why they are different, $(1)$ and $(2)$ that is.

Comment: In (1) you are talking about *some* $k,$ for which you intend to prove $P(k+1)$ (as a result of the 2 proof rules of my previous comment). In (2) you are only assuming that $P(~)$ holds for some (unknown and unnamed) natural number, and this assumption is of no use in an induction proof.

Comment: Is the number not named $k$ In $(2)$? And doesn't "for some" mean "there exists", meaning "for some" is $2$ and not $1$? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1378906/whats-logical-symbol-for-for-some

Comment: There is no named number in (2) (as I said, "the letter $k$ may be replaced...").  For some = there exists is indeed in (2) and not (1). In (1) you fix some $k$ and you make an assumption (and then a proof) about that $k.$ In (2) you only make an (unusable) assumption about the property $P.$

Comment: Thanks Anne this really helped. Now I do not mean to sound like a broken record but what is the defining difference between $1$ and $2$ that means the $k$ cannot be replaced in $1$ and hence it is different to $2$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "$\forall k {\in} \mathbb {N}\;P(k)$"

Here, $k$ is a **bound variable** pointing to an ***arbitrary*** natural number, which has property $P.$

> "$\exists k {\in} \mathbb {N}\;P(k)$"

Here, $k$ is a **bound variable** pointing to an ***unspecified*** natural number that has property $P.$

> "$k \in \mathbb {N}$ and $P(k)$"

Here, depending on the context, either:

1. $k$ is a ***particular*** natural-number **constant** that has property $P.$

or:

2. $k$ is a **free** natural-number **variable** that has property $P.$ Only in this case, the given formula is an open formula rather than a sentence, and has no definite truth value until $k$ is instantiated.

---

> "Assume that $P(k)$ **for some** natural number $k$."

As observed by Bram28, this sounds like a common phrasing in the inductive step of an induction proof. What's actually happening is that we are considering an arbitrary natural number $k,$ then assuming that $P(k)$ is true, then showing that $P(k+1)$ is consequently true; all in all, the inductive step is showing that

- $\color{green}{\textbf{for each}}$ natural number $k,$ if $P(k)$ is true, then $P(k+1)$ is true

  $\color{green}{\boldsymbol\forall} k{\in}\mathbb N\;\big(P(k)\implies P(k+1)\big);$

an equivalent phrasing is

- $\color{green}{\textbf{given some arbitrary}}$ natural number $k,$ if $P(k)$ is true, then $P(k+1)$ is true,

which unfortunately sounds like

- $\color{red}{\textbf{for some}}$ natural number $k,$ if $P(k)$ is true, then $P(k+1)$ is true

  $\color{red}{\boldsymbol\exists} k{\in}\mathbb N\;\big(P(k)\implies P(k+1)\big),$

[understandably throwing people off](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4738649/21813).

---

**Reply to the OP's comment**

> Could you elaborate on the differences between the two "$k∈\mathbb N$ and $P(k)$" cases, and which one we use for induction?

The inductive step can be rewritten as $$\forall k \;\big(k\in\mathbb N\text{ and }P(k)\implies P(k+1)\big),$$ where $\text“k\in\mathbb N\text{ and }P(k)\text”$ in isolation corrresponds to the second case above.

Comment: Related: [Difference between “for some $k$” and “for some arbitrary $k$”](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4738649/21813)

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you are bringing this up in the context of an inductive proof, whose inductive step usually starts out with something like

> "Assume that $P(k)$ for some number $k$".

Now, the use of 'some' here makes it *sound* like your (2): $\exists k \in \mathbb {N} : P(k)$

However, this is certainly *not* the assumption of the inductive step. Consider: suppose we use that assumption. We could then also suppose that $k_0$ is one of those numbers, and maybe we can even show that that means that $k_0 +1$ has property $P$ as well. OK, so what have we then proven?  All we would have proven is that there is some number such that it and its successor have property $P$. In logic: we would have shown that $\exists k \in \mathbb {N} : P(k) \land P(k+1)$. Or, discharging the assumption, we obtain $$\exists k \in \mathbb {N} : P(k) \to \exists k \in \mathbb {N} : P(k) \land P(k+1)$$ But that is not what the inductive step tries to show.

The inductive step tries to show that $\forall k \in \mathbb {N} : P(k) \to P(k+1)$. We do that by picking some arbitrary number, assume that it has property $P$, and use that to show that $P(k+1)$.

So here is the difference: instead of assuming $\exists k \in \mathbb {N} : P(k)$, we simply assume $P(k)$ *once* $k$ has been introduced as an arbitrary number. So, the assumption is really just $P(k)$. Once we obtain $P(k+1)$, we can discharge the assumption and get $P(k) \to P(k+1)$, and by noting that $k$ was an arbitrarily chosen number, we can generalize this for all numbers, and thus obtain $$\forall k \in \mathbb {N} : P(k) \to P(k+1)$$

So, the assumption is really more like your (1), where $k$ is a free variable. Indeed, when the inductive step starts out with:

> "Assume that $P(k)$ for some number $k$"

you should really read that as:

> "Assume that $P(k)$ for some *arbitrary* number $k$"

or, better yet, as:

> "Let $k$ be some *arbitrary* number and assume that $P(k)$"

It is $k$ being an arbitrary number (as reflected by it being free) that allows you to conclude with the universal statement that you want.

Comment: Thanks so much. $(1)$ is definitely the correct inductive assumption!

Comment: @Mathguy Yes!  Hope this analysis was helpful.

Comment: $x,y$ are real numbers here. I would like to ask how do you make sense of $\forall x: y = 5x$ (where $y$ is free) and the formula $y = 5x$ (where $x,y$ are free). I know that $\forall x \exists ! y: y = 5x$ is true always.

Comment: @Mathguy Much depends on the context in which these expressions are used.  In the context of an inductive proof, the use of $k$ in $P(k)$ is understood to be an arbitrary natural number. In some other proof context, the $y$ and $x$ used in $y = 5x$ could likewise refer to arbitrary contexts. But more likely is that you will find the expression $y = 5x$ within some mathematical context where the $x$ and $y$ are specific numbers whose value we may not necessarily know. Or, it could be our description or even definition of a function.  Symbols can be used in many, many, different ways!

Answer (score 0):

"Assume $\exists k \in \mathbb{N} : P(k)$"

Assume there exists at least one natural number $k$ such that $P(k)$ holds true. The specific natural number for which $P$ is true is not named. You are merely told that one exists for which $P$ is true.

"Assume $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and $P(k)$."

$k$ is assumed to be a specific natural number for which $P(k)$ holds true.

Comment: Why is the number in $2$ not named when we use the symbol $k$ in both instances but it only "Names" the number in the first way?

Comment: are both statements a part of the same proof? does one follow after the other?

Comment: I am talking about when we start the proof, the two different statements being the first one I write down. If I write $\exists k$ why does that mean that the number I am referring to is not named, I used a letter $k$ surely? (Here I have not used $k$ before this instance)

Comment: When the variable $k$ is bound to the existential quantifier $\exists$, it does not represent a specific object in the domain; rather, it represents any arbitrary or random object in the domain. And the existential quantifier effectively tells you that $P$ holds true for at least one of the arbitrary objects, without naming them. In the other statement, the existential quantifier has been removed and you are being asked to treat $k$ no longer as an unnamed object but as one of the specific objects for which $P$ is true.

Comment: Technically, a different letter should be used whenever a quantifier is eliminated and a variable, in this case $k$, is instantiated. It helps to avoid the kind of confusion you're currently experiencing. But sometimes people do not use a different letter. Instead, they simply ask you to stop treating the letter as a variable and start treating it as a constant.

Comment: Alright, so when we start the proof, we have a choice on $1$ or $2$, if we chose $2$ we have effectively deduced nothing useful, if we chose $1$ then we can construct a proof by induction, got it! And if we mistakenly write down $2$, to be extra neat we should write down $1$ but with a different letter instead.

Comment: it might be helpful if you actually explain what you're trying to prove and write down the first few lines of your proof. then we can give you some feedback

Comment: Actually, by reading your older comments, its making much more sense, do you know any good things to read to get more understanding on logic/free/bound variables and stuff like this? So I can answer questions like, why does $\exists$ not name a number on my own?

Comment: Yes! see https://www.amazon.com/Concise-Introduction-Logic-Patrick-Hurley/dp/1305958098/ref=pd_lpo_sccl_2/140-1517274-6961447?pd_rd_w=kwYFj&content-id=amzn1.sym.116f529c-aa4d-4763-b2b6-4d614ec7dc00&pf_rd_p=116f529c-aa4d-4763-b2b6-4d614ec7dc00&pf_rd_r=1DEBD776H1KXDYJK0P9P&pd_rd_wg=wvywt&pd_rd_r=95e80f0d-f250-4a38-919b-d7af61c02eb8&pd_rd_i=1305958098&psc=1